# differentiate an expression from both sides

Tags: derivatives

Suppose we are given $$x=\cos \theta$$
Why does $$ \frac{d}{d\theta}=-\sin \theta\frac{d}{dx}$$

Since intuitively, I would have written $$ -\sin \theta \frac{d}{d\theta}=\frac{d}{dx}$$

As $$x=y$$ differentiate at the same time give $$dx=dy$$
So I’m assuming they used some formula that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the *chain rule*:  suppose $A$ is some expression depending on $x$, hence depending also on $\theta$. By the chain rule
$$\frac{\mathrm d A}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu \theta}=\frac{\mathrm d A}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu \theta}=-\sin\theta\frac{\mathrm d A}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x},\quad\text{whence }\quad \frac{\mathrm d \phantom{A}}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu \theta}=-\sin\theta\,\frac{\mathrm d \phantom{A}}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}$$
as a differential operator.

Answer (score 0):

Well. are you familiar with the "chain rule"?  That is what is being used!

If  x is some function of $\theta$, $x(\theta)$, then, for any function, y(x), by the chain rule $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dx}$.
Here, $x= cos(\theta)$ so $\frac{dx}{d\theta}= -sin(\theta)$.  So $\frac{dy}{d\theta}= -sin(\theta)\frac{dy}{dx}$